# Rollup excludes the files >2 mb in the build?

Tags: javascript, typescript, build, webassembly, rollup

I have been working with a project where I needed to use an npm package which has some `.wasm` files which are >2 mb. When I ran the build with rollup, the files were excluded. They were missing in the `node_modules` folder.

Is there a elegant way to fix this problem?

Apologies for being subjective.

Comment: How are the WASM files invoked during runtime?